# Haskell: Use Map only for specific constructor

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

I have defined the following data type:

```
data Item = Item { name :: String, subitems :: [Itemunit] } deriving (Show, Eq)

data Itemunit = Itemunit Item | Dataunit Datau deriving (Show, Eq)

data Datau = Datau { dataName ::String } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Now I have a "tree" defined by those items. I want to get a String List which contains for example the Names of all Items (or of all Dataunits). My first idea was to use map, but how can I filter so it only recursively calls itself when Itemunit used the Itemunit constructor?

So basically what I need is this:

```
getAsStringList = name : map getAsStringList subitems
```

but obviously I need to make sure getAsStringList is only called if the subitem is an Itemunit and not if it is a Dataunit. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to filter on the data constructors:

```
getAsStringList :: Item -> [String]
getAsStringList (Item nm si) = nm : [ nmi | Itemunit ii <- si, nmi <- getAsStringList ii ]
```

We need to use `nmi <- getAsStringList ii`, since this will return a *list* of `String`s, and we thus need to enumerate over it.

You can also make use of [**`concatMap :: Foldable t => (a -> [b]) -> t a -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap)  to concatenate the items after mapping:

```
getAsStringList :: Item -> [String]
getAsStringList (Item nm si) = nm : concatMap getAsStringList [ ii | Itemunit ii <- si ]
```

You however use the same data constructor (`Dataunit`) twice, you should use another data constructor for one of the types.

Comment: @Richi: your function needs to take a type as input type. That can be `Item` or `Dataunit`, or something else, but not the two together. You can also define a typeclass for ad-hoc polymorphism.

Comment: @Richi: why not? It is not the `concatMap` that is the problem, but the mapping function that you use. So if you use another `concatMap` that maps `... -> [String]`, then this can work.